# Como hacer una arrow función en react para que se ejecute una sola vez y guarde los datos en sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, function

Hola comunidad estoy desarrollando una aplicación en react y necesito implementar una petición a **Active directory** para extraer la información del usuario logeado, a través de **Microsoft graph**. Ocupo eliminar el uso del botón y el onclick y que la función se ejecute una sola vez.
Necesito ayuda en react para que esta **función se ejecute una sola vez** y **guarde los datos en sessionStorage**.

```
  function ProfileContent() {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(null);
  const name = accounts[0] && accounts[0].name;

 
  function RequestProfileData() {
      const request = {...loginRequest, account: accounts[0]};
      

      instance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then((response) => {
         callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response));
      }).catch((e) => {
          instance.acquireTokenPopup(request).then((response) => {
              callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response));
      });
    });
  }

  return (
      <>
          <h5 className="card-title">Welcome {name}</h5>
          <h5> {name}</h5>
          {graphData ? 
             <ProfileData graphData={graphData}/>
              :
              <Button variant="secondary" onClick={RequestProfileData}>Request Profile information</Button>
          }        
      </>
  );
};
```

Comment: No queda claro si necesitas que NUNCA mas busque los datos si es que ya estan gaurdados en el sessionStorage o si solo queres que no se muestre el botón.

Comment: Correcto me gustaría que no se muestre el botón y que la petición se realice una sola vez para que los datos se guarden en el sessionStorage. Así los puedo utilizar durante la sesion.